# Will Render Animation always take this long?

Tags: rendering, animation, export

I simply clicked the animation button after following an online tutorial. So all the settings are where they should be. But should the rendering really be taking hours? It finally hit frame ten after about two hours, which is PAINFULLY slow. Are there any ways to increase the speed of it? It's already using 100% CPU. Thank you in advance!

Because of the reputation system, I was only able to post one screenshot in addition to the blend file.

Blend file here: [image]

Ethan

[image]

Comment: Welcome to BSE, it would be helpful to attach screen shots of your Render Panel, and upload your .blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1459" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1459/)

There is the blend file. The only thing I changed was the text from "Prism" to ethanpenn5.

Comment: A single frame takes me about 9 minutes to render on an i7 4790, so yes, it will probably take hours.

Comment: Holy cow! I didn't know that it was that extreme! I don't even want to know what the professional filmmakers must go through to create movies like Star Wars and other movies like that!

Comment: Actually, the proffesional filmakers have "render farms". This renders multiple scenes at the same time